# How do I turn off text formatting on save in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autoformatting

I don't know why my code is auto formatted on save and for some reason changing the layout. I figured out this was due to auto format on save. How do I turn auto save off in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**For Windows:**

Here are the some basics steps to be followed to turn off auto complete.

Step:1 - Press `Ctrl + Shift + P` to open **Command Palette**. Then screen like below image appears.
[image]

Step:2 - Type Save without formatting and click the matching option available. **It either commands on click or redirects you to next interface.**

If it works on click then it's fine and if your are redirected to next screen just uncheck auto format option under onsave. For me it worked on cick to the shown command.

**For Mac:**

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> and then <kbd>S</kbd>

Answer (score 22):

Default: `Ctrl + k + Ctrl + Shift + s` on  Windows.

Answer (score 18):

This was [introduced in back in 2018](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/38695#issuecomment-423422531), the keybinding (on MacOS) is:

```
Cmd+K S
```

For keybindings for your own system, search for the command `saveWithoutFormatting` in the Command Palette

Answer (score 7):

For others having the same problem and if Save without format is inconvenient to do every time and if you want permanent settings for saving without format here are the steps:

Edit the settings.json file. You can do that with the command "Open Settings (JSON)"

press Command + Shift + P (to open the command palette)
and start typing the command "Open Settings (JSON)" and select from the suggestions.
[image: VS Code command]

The setting is named formatOnSave and you should set it to false, to disable it. It can be present multiple times for different types of things.

"editor.formatOnSave": false

It is best to search for "OnSave", because there might also be other settings that are doing formatting on Save, for example:

"editor.codeActionsOnSave"

Comment: `It is best to search for "OnSave"` this *saved* me.

Answer (score 2):

In mac you can save without formatting with the following shortcut, (No need to touch the config):
[image: shortcut]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to open the command palette every-time, you can change the `Ctrl/Cmd + S` shortcut to make the action  *"Save without Formatting"*
and remove the shortcut for *"Save"*.

Answer (score 1):

### Actually none of the answers are satisfying enough

**As of 2023**

**1-** Go to `File > Preferences > Settings`

[image]

---

**2-** Type in the search bar `format on save`

[image]

---

**3-** There you'll find the option **Format on Save** checked. Uncheck it and you're done!

**NB: The advantage of this technique is that you're doing it once and for all, i.e. for all the files (unlike the one of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Sift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> which does it for the current file)**