# Git detects changes for the whole file once opened but not changes were made. Using windows and vscode

Tags: javascript, html, git, visual-studio-code

I have created a repo on Github, and pushed exercise files to practice on. When I open one of these files and hit `ctrl+save` or add a single line of code the editor marks everything as changed. Even when I have made not changes or just a single line change.

For example, on the first image - I did not change anything but `ctrl+save` changed the formatting which should not be a problem.

[image]

In the second image, it is possible to see that almost the entire file changed but in reality is the same

[image]

I am using VSCode and Git with the latest updates on Windows.

Much appreciate any guidance!

Comment: Sounds like you have an EOL setting (in git) in place that might be changing files.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because on the save action you have some kind of automatic code formatter tool enabled, like [prettier](https://prettier.io/).

If you want to skip this formatting action then this might help: [How do I turn off text formatting on save in visual studio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63480680/how-do-i-turn-off-text-formatting-on-save-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Thank you! your answer combined with @eftshift0 helped! 
I did change the formatting rules on vscode and this added the following in a `.vscode file`

` ` `  
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modifications"
}

` ` `
Also updated git